# Function involving the Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

I Have 
$$k(z)=\Gamma\left(\frac12+z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12-z\right)\cos(\pi z)$$
and wish to find a relation linking $k(z+1)$ and $k(z)$. Substituting $z+1$ and using the recurrence relation of the gamma function
$$\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$$
and using
$$\cos(\pi +z)=-\cos(z)$$
I obtain:
$$k(z+1)=-\left(z+\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(z+\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(-\frac12-z\right)\cos(\pi z)$$
However I am stuck with what to do with the $\Gamma\left(-\frac12-z\right)$ term.

Comment: *Hint.* $w\Gamma(w) = \Gamma(w+1)$.

Comment: Do you know Euler's reflection formula?

Comment: Do you mean to use the reflection formula with $ z=-z-1/2 $. So that $ \Gamma(-1/2-z)=\frac{\pi}{-\Gamma(z+3/2)cos(\pi z)}=\frac{\pi}{-(z+1/2)\Gamma(z+1/2)cos(\pi z)} $ but this would then give $  k(z+1)=\pi $ I assume I am making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from where you left off with $$k(z+1)$$
We have
$$-\left(\frac12+z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12+z\right)\Gamma\left(-\frac12-z\right)\cos(\pi z)$$
$$=\left(-\frac12-z\right)\Gamma\left(-\frac12-z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12+z\right)\cos(\pi z)$$
$$=\Gamma\left(-\frac12-z+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12+z\right)\cos(\pi z)$$
$$=\Gamma\left(\frac12-z\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12+z\right)\cos(\pi z)$$
Therefore
$$k(z+1)=k(z)$$